# Reload ASP.NET page from Page_Error event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Our ASP.NET page uses bunch of 3rd party controls inside of an UpdatePanel. Sometimes they throw errors, not catchable in any other places but `Page_Error` event. When this happens, we need to refresh the page. Is there a way to do this from Error event? We attempted to send JS back to the client:

```
Protected Sub Page_Error(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Error

    Dim ex = Server.GetLastError

    If ex.Message.Contains("Specific string from controls' error") Then 
        Server.ClearError()
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType, "JSCode", "location.reload(true);", True)
    End If

End Sub
```

But this doesn't work, throws an error of its own:

> Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown
>   error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status
>   code returned from the server was: 500

And I couldn't find anything related in the event viewer.

Is this reload possible?

Comment: What's the error? And your if statment isn't finished...

Comment: @the_lotus there's a condition in `if` in real code, i just left it generic. Error thrown by MS Ajax library is generic "500" I don't see anything corresponding to it in event viewer. It looks like at this point in page lifecycle `RegisterStartupScript` is not allowed (I will update the question to make it more clear)

Comment: You might be stuck at doing a Response.Redirect

Comment: @the_lotus can u post it as an answer? I didn't try it initially because ordinary Response.Redirect doesn't work inside of Update panel. But it seems to work perfectly in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be stuck at doing a Response.Redirect since on the Page_Error I don't think you can submit javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your comment, its an ajax error. Therefore, a server response would not be rendered here. The client browser expects the response to be either data or partial view/user control or similar chunk and not a complete html page. However, with this exception, the response is returned as a complete html page (an error page in this case). As a result, the client fails to handle that ajax response properly. You would have to catch that ajax error event and redirect/refresh within that handler.

You can take a look at my post [here](http://sajidq.wordpress.com/2014/04/16/session-validation-in-ajax-calls/)

Comment: Thanks for the info, looks interesting, but as @the_lotus pointed out in that case ordinary Response.Redirect works as well